# SQL Query Help - searching on multiple 'pairs' or data

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling to work out how to do a SQL query on a database that I have.

I have a view (which can be changed) which shows the relationships between the tables.

[image]

This creates a view as follows:

[image]

What I need to be able to do is search on one or more 'Attribute Pairs'

for example

I want to search for records with:

```
(
 (AttributeName='FileExtension' AND AttributeValue='.pdf')
AND (AttributeName='AccountNumber' AND AttributeValue='ABB001'
)
```

As you can tell, this is not working as AttributeName cant be two things at once. I have this working with an OR filter, but I want it to find records that have all attribute pairs

```
SELECT        
dbo.SiconDMSDocument.SiconDMSDocumentID, 
dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.SiconDMSAttributeID, 
dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.AttributeFriendlyName, 
dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.AttributeName,
dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.AttributeValue, 
dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.DataType, 
dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType.SiconDMSDocumentTypeID, 
dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType.DocumentTypeName,
dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType.DocumentTypeFriendlyName, 
dbo.SiconDMSModule.SiconDMSModuleID, 
dbo.SiconDMSModule.ModuleName, 
dbo.SiconDMSModule.ModuleFriendlyName,
dbo.SiconDMSDocument.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModuleID
FROM dbo.SiconDMSDocument 
INNER JOIN dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute ON dbo.SiconDMSDocument.SiconDMSDocumentID = dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.SiconDMSDocumentID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SiconDMSAttribute ON dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.SiconDMSAttributeID = dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.SiconDMSAttributeID
AND
( 
    (dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.AttributeName = 'Reference' AND dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.AttributeValue='12345')
OR (dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.AttributeName = 'AccountNumber' AND dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.AttributeValue='ABB001')

)
INNER JOIN dbo.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModule ON dbo.SiconDMSDocument.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModuleID = dbo.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModule.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModuleID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType ON dbo.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModule.SiconDMSDocumentTypeID = dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType.SiconDMSDocumentTypeID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SiconDMSModule ON dbo.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModule.SiconDMSModuleID = dbo.SiconDMSModule.SiconDMSModuleID
WHERE  
(dbo.SiconDMSDocument.Deleted = 0) 
AND (dbo.SiconDMSDocumentAttribute.Deleted = 0) 
AND (dbo.SiconDMSAttribute.Deleted = 0) 
AND (dbo.SiconDMSDocumentType.Deleted = 0) 
AND (dbo.SiconDMSDocumentTypeModule.Deleted = 0) 
AND (dbo.SiconDMSModule.Deleted = 0)
```

Are there any SQL functions that will allow me to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your complicated query has to do with the question of searching for attribute pairs.

Assuming you want the document ids that have both attributes:

```
select SiconDMSDocumentID
from yourview y
where (AttributeName = 'FileExtension' AND AttributeValue = '.pdf') or
      (AttributeName = 'AccountNumber' AND AttributeValue = 'ABB001'
group by SiconDMSDocumentID
having count(*) = 2;
```

Or, if the attributes could have multiple values:

```
having count(distinct AttributeName) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Ill give it a try now.

Comment: the having count(*) = 2.  is the 2 the number of attributes im searching on?

Comment: ok, looks like that will work, but I will need to create a stored procedure which takes unlimited number of parameters to search on. much like the c# params keyword

Comment: @WraithNath . . . Yes, the 2 is the number of attributes.